# Lipschitz functions defined on a grid

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, continuity

Assume we have a space G of Lipschitz function $g:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb R$.
Moreover, we have a grid $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$ covering the interval $[0,1]$,
such that $max_{i,j}|x_i-x_j| \leq c_n$. If it is an equally spaced grid, we would have  $x_i= i/(n+1)$ and $c_n= 1/(n+1)$.
Intuitively, I feel that if the lipschitz constant and $c_n$ are low enough the functions will be uniquely defined, that is if $g,h\in G$ and $g(x_i) = h(x_i) \forall i=1,...,n$ would imply that $g=h$.
Do you have any idea how could I show that? I feel it should be classical result in analysis but I can't find it.

Comment: I do not think this is true. What if $g=-h=\prod (x-x_i)$?